Generating values and creating heatmap from three different point vector layers in QGIS
In QGIS I would like to turn what I have into a heatmap.
I have 3 different sets of points that go across the map of the UK (see the image attached) that represent coastal marine habitats. What I want to do is add a value for each set of points and then create a heatmap based on this.
So for example, I want to give each green point a value of 5, each blue point a value of 3, and each brown point a value of 8 and then create a heatmap that shows the change in this value between the points.

How can I do this?

First I would merge the three layers using the 'Merge Vector layers' tool:
Vector --> Data Management Tools --> Merge Vector layers
Select your three point layers as the input layers and an appropriate CRS. You can save to a more permanent data type or just leave it as temporary:

In the resulting merged layer, there will be a field called 'layer' containing the name of the originating layer which you can use to generate your values. Using the Field Calculator, create a new field with something like the following:
CASE WHEN "Layer" = 'Name of layer 1' THEN 3
WHEN "Layer" = 'Name of layer 2' THEN 5
WHEN "Layer" = 'Name of layer 3' THEN 8
END

Then you can set set the symbology to show a heatmap. In the new merged layer properties, go to symbology and select 'Heatmap' from the dropdown, your preferred colour ramp, and select the new field you created in the previous step in 'Weight points by'. Bear in mind this will apply greater weighting to the higher values instead of point density, but I assume this is your intention. You'll probably want to set the opacity in the layer rendering to something like 50% too:

